# Flash Bitmap Vs MovieClip

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

What are the Advantages and Disadvantages over the Bitmap and MovieClip in Flash.

Give me your thoughts.
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

They're not comparable objects; you don't use them for the same things. Both MovieClip and Bitmap are DisplayObjects, so you can add either of them to the stage, and scale them, or rotate them, or whatever. However, MovieClip is a general-purpose container, which can contain any number of children - graphics, bitmaps, other movieclips, etc. But MovieClips cannot contain or display raw bitmap data. Bitmap is the reverse - it cannot contain children, so the only useful thing you do with Bitmaps is to attach BitmapData objects to them.

In other words, when you want to display an image in the screen, and your image is in the form of a BitmapData, the way to do this is to attach your BitmapData to a Bitmap, and then add that Bitmap to a MovieClip that is on your stage. You can't reverse those two roles - you can't attach BitmapDatas to MovieClips, or add children to Bitmaps. So I don't think there's anything to compare.